# I'm making a function to reduce the timer every 1000 milliseconds, so is there a way to reduce the remaining milliseconds if I restart?

Tags: javascript

Before you read it...
I'm not good at English, so I'd appreciate it if you could understand.

I'm creating a function that reduces the timer every 1000 milliseconds, but if I restart it, is there a way to reduce the number of milliseconds left at the point of stop?

1. Press the button on the timer to perform the play function, decreasing the timer every 1000 milliseconds.
2. Pressing the timer button one more time will perform the stop function and stop the timer.
3. Press the timer button again to perform the play function.
   Assuming the timer runs for 10 seconds, performing the stop function when 5 seconds are left, there are milliseconds, such as 5:53, not exactly 5 seconds. So if we start again, we want to reduce the remaining milliseconds, not 1,000 milliseconds.

[Tried]
We wanted to find the milliseconds of the initial start time and stop time and convert the remaining milliseconds in the `test()` function to use it as the timeout for `setInterval()`. Next, to reduce 1000 milliseconds normally, I tried to create a timeout from inside `setInterval()` to 1000 milliseconds, but the result was not good.

```
const minute = document.querySelector('.minute');
const second = document.querySelector('.second');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

let playTime = 10; // second
let start;
let pause;
let intervalTimeout;
let interval;

function play(){
    if(!start){        intervalTimeout = 1000;
        start = new Date(Date.now()).getMilliseconds();
    } else{
        intervalTimeout = test(); // 
    }
    timeForm(playTime);
    interval = setInterval(()=>{
        intervalTimeout = 1000;
        timeForm(--playTime);
        if(playTime === 0){
            clearInterval(interval);
            playTime = 10;
        }
        
    },intervalTimeout);
    
};
function stop(){
    pause = new Date(Date.now()).getMilliseconds();

    clearInterval(interval);
    
};

function test(){
    if(start > pause){
        return intervalTimeout = start - pause;
    } else if( start < stop){
        return intervalTimeout = start + (1000-pause);
    }
}

function timeForm(time){
    let m = ((time / 60) > 9)? (time / 60) : '0'+(time / 60);
    let s = ((time % 60) > 9)? (time % 60) : '0'+(time % 60);
    minute.innerHTML = `${parseInt(m)}`;
    second.innerHTML = `${s}`;
};


function btnToggle(){
    button.classList.toggle('stop');
    return button.classList.contains('stop');
}


button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if(btnToggle()){
        play();    
    } else{
        stop();
    }
    
});
```

Comment: I guess you need to read about the concept of generators https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*

Answer (score 0):

I think Javascript closures would do the trick for this.Here is a simple codesnippet to help you . Also the link for the docs is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures. Hope this helps.

```
function start() {
  const startTime = 100;
  return function () {
    return startTime;
  };
}

function pause() {
  const pauseTime = start();
}
 
const stopTime = start()-10;

console.log(pauseTime()); // 100
console.log(stopTime()); // 90
```